# PHP - Variable returns NULL, but it shouldn't?

Tags: php, json

So I am trying to make, code will get certain parts matching ID's from the JSON array.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($response, true);
//-------------------------------------
$invIndexes = [];
foreach($json->rgInventory as $index){
    $invIndexes = $index;
}
//-------------------------------------
$makearray = (array)$invIndexes;
for($id = 0;$id < count($invIndexes);$id++){
    $index = $makearray[$id];
    $item = $json->rgDescriptions[$json->rgInventory[$index]->classid + "_" + $json->rgInventory[$index]->instanceid];
    if($item->tradeable != 1){
        continue;
    }
    $ItemName = $item->market_hash_name;
}
var_dump($ItemName);
```

Here's the JSON: http://pastebin.ca/3591035

The $ItemName return's `NULL` but it shouldn't (At least I think that). Maybe someone can spot the mistake what I've been doing here :/

Comment: imagine that `$json->rgInventory` is empty array, what value will be in $ItemName after the execution?

Comment: then change `$invIndexes = $index` to `$invIndexes[] = $index`

Comment: Didn't change anything though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are you using true in json decode `$json = json_decode($response, true);`, then it will return an associative array, so you can access the value form array simply like this `$json['rgInventory']` not `$json->rgInventory`

To create `$invIndexes` array use this:

```
$invIndexes = array();
foreach($json['rgInventory'] as $index){
    $invIndexes[] = $index['id'];
}
```

Here you will get `$invIndexes` the in your for loo you are again using `$json->rgDescriptions` to access values, change this to `$json['rgInventory']` and for all other values use array keys  like this `$json['rgInventory']['index']['class']`

No need of this `$makearray = (array)$invIndexes;` directly use `$invIndexes`

```
$index = $invIndexes[$id];
$item = $json['rgDescriptions'][$json['rgInventory'][$index]['classid']."_".$json['rgInventory'][$index]['instanceid']];
```

Another mistake is that in your $item there is not any key `tradeable`, its `tradable` an use like this

```
if($item['tradeable'] != 1){
    continue;
}

 $ItemName = $item['market_hash_name'];
```

At last `var_dump($ItemName);`

Comment: Alright, I've fixed up my code now a bit. I've found out that if I put there that classid_instanceid, then it returns null, but if I look my json, then everything is correct. What could be the issue?

Comment: Code what I tried: `echo json_encode($json['rgDescriptions']['1011934686_480207147']);` but returns null.. json has that value here's little picture: http://prntscr.com/b0jifn

Comment: try `echo "<pre>"; print_r($json['rgDescriptions']['1011934686_480207147']);` and see output...

Comment: Nothing comes, seems like Null ?

Comment: is your `classid_instanceid` `1011934686_480207147` has values further ??

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($json['rgDescriptions']);` Immediately after json_decode()  of response and show me the o/p

Comment: In there there's no 1011934686

Comment: My bad.. That's happens if Im blind hahaha

Comment: Basically, Something is wrong with that foreach, because seems like it doesn't get the "id's" in the rgInventory. Here's picture what "ID's" it basically has to get, to get that $item.. http://prntscr.com/b0jww4

Comment: updated the answer check foreach loop we forgot to use key id in loop `$invIndexes[] = $index['id'];`

Comment: Hmm.. Here's now the response `"8""6""6""6""3""0""6""5""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""0""5""6""6"` if I use code: `echo json_encode($index[2]);`

Comment: where you are printing this `echo json_encode($index[2])` ??

Comment: In for loop :D :D, but basically "same response" will be for the `$item` as well

Comment: why `index[2]` ? first of change var name `$index` to smthing else like `$idx` and try `$idx = $invIndexes[$id];`
`$item = $json['rgDescriptions'][$json['rgInventory'][$idx ]['classid']."_".$json['rgInventory'][$idx ]['instanceid']];`

Comment: Why not? If I may ask

Comment: Now it repeats somekind of number seems so :D, `6666665555555555555555555555555555555555521` example

Comment: because `$index` is not an array in for loop, we are using it as a variable... in which we are declaring `$invIndexes[$id];` and usinf  `$index` as key to get item..

Comment: If I just do `echo $idx` then it's correct, just there is ALL those numbers, but not separated.

Comment: `print_r($invIndexes); die;` after foreach loop and check what's the o/p

Comment: Numbers are right now. There's still something with `$item` I think. So like you can see that, I have code in `for` loop which is `$ItemName = $item['market_hash_name']; if I call it after the for loop, it's empty or in the for loop it is empty.

Comment: Shows me info about 1 item.

Comment: Removed line "tradeable"

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks :).

Comment: @JamesPraha, oohh Thank God :D :D  as i've already said in answer that change tradeable to tradable ;P and I need an up vote also... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument `true` to `json_decode` tells it to convert JSON objects into PHP associative arrays rather than PHP objects. But using syntax like `$json->rgDescriptions` requires `$json` to be an object; for an array it should be `$json['rgDescriptions']`.

So either change all your uses of `$json` to use array syntax, or remove the `true` argument from `json_decode`. The latter should be easier.

Also, this line:

```
$invIndexes = $index;
```

should be:

```
$invIndexes[] = $index;
```

But you could replace that loop with just:

```
$invIndexes = $json->rgInventory;
```

Comment: Hmm, Seems I still can't get it working for me :/.. It seems like it doesn't add those "ID's" to the array.